# AWS Cognito add user to a group from Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

admittedly, this is my first attempt at doing anything with Cognito, but I am having trouble adding a user to a user group via lambda. here is the lambda code:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({apiVersion: '2016-04-18'});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    var params = {
        GroupName: 'ROLE_ADMIN',
        // UserPoolId: 'arn:aws:cognito-idp:us-east-1:23453453453:userpool/us-east-1_XXX',
        UserPoolId: 'us-east-1_XXX',
        // Username: 'user@email.com'
        Username: 'ec12f604-a83c-4c76-856b-3acd9ca70562'
      }

console.log('before')
  cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminAddUserToGroup(params, function(err, data) {
    console.log(params)
    if (err) console.log("Error");
    else     console.log("Success");
  });

  console.log('after')

  console.log("Executed.");

  context.succeed(event);
};
```

I have added the AWS resources to the lambda

Amazon CloudWatch Logs
Amazon Cognito Identity
Amazon Cognito Sync
Amazon Cognito User Pools
Amazon SNS
Identity And Access Management

here is the output:

> Function Logs: START RequestId: e6fb3c51-3928-40e1-b0c4-f7a2d9054ef0
>   Version: $LATEST
>   2019-10-29T19:04:58.516Z  e6fb3c51-3928-40e1-b0c4-f7a2d9054ef0    INFO    before
>   2019-10-29T19:04:59.017Z  e6fb3c51-3928-40e1-b0c4-f7a2d9054ef0    INFO    after
>   2019-10-29T19:04:59.018Z  e6fb3c51-3928-40e1-b0c4-f7a2d9054ef0    INFO    Executed.
>   END RequestId: e6fb3c51-3928-40e1-b0c4-f7a2d9054ef0 REPORT RequestId:
>   e6fb3c51-3928-40e1-b0c4-f7a2d9054ef0  Duration: 657.73 ms Billed
>   Duration: 700 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 37 MB  Init
>   Duration: 464.08 ms

what I am not seeing is the `cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminAddUserToGroup` being called, and the test runs, but it doesn't look like any uses are being added to the `ROLE_ADMIN` group. what should I be doing to be adding users into a group?

any input would be greatly appreciated... thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, you can not see `Success` or `Error` log.

Action `adminAddUserToGroup` has been canceled before it finishes itself, because you call `context.succeed(event)` to `kill` the function immediately.

How to solve, just wait until the action finished, then `kill` the function. In general we have 2 options:

1. Do right with `callback` function (recommended):

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({ apiVersion: '2016-04-18' });

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

  var params = {
    GroupName: 'ROLE_ADMIN',
    // UserPoolId: 'arn:aws:cognito-idp:us-east-1:23453453453:userpool/us-east-1_XXX',
    UserPoolId: 'us-east-1_XXX',
    // Username: 'user@email.com'
    Username: 'ec12f604-a83c-4c76-856b-3acd9ca70562'
  }

  console.log('before')
  cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminAddUserToGroup(params, function (err, data) {
    console.log(params)
    if (err) console.log("Error");
    else console.log("Success");

    // when the action finished
    console.log('after');

    console.log("Executed.");

    context.succeed(event);
  });
};
```

---

2. Tell to the Lambda function that `wait until the call stack is clear`: Insert `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = true` to the first line of function (before declare `params` variable)

Comment: not to be pedantic, but can you explicitly state which is option one, and wich is option 2? I am assuming the code in the text box is all of the first option, and telling the function to wait until the call stack is clear is option 2?

Comment: @StillLearningToCode ohh, you are right, I updated my answer! Thanks!